# Version Git Repo for Composer Use - Git/Composer

Tags: php, git, cakephp, composer-php

**Scenario**

I have a Plugin in PHP that I've written and want to keep it as a private repository. I want to set up the versioning in Git. I know there are tags for this, but don't know how the convention works for Composer.

**Current `composer.json` for my package/plugin:**

```
{
    "name": "Test/Upload",
    "description": "Useful functions for image uploading.",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    }
}
```

**Current `composer.json` for my project to include the above package/plugin:**

```
{
    "name": "multistepform",
    "require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": "2.6.*",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}
```

Currently I have no tags in the package/plugin.

**Qs**

1) Does Composer *require* tags in a repository in order for it to use it?

2) How should one tag their private repository for use with Composer?

3) How to include this package in a different project (using the above context)?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @tigrang's comment and list out the explicit steps:

- add your git repo using "repositories" in your composer.json
- tag your package with a version number (I suggest using [Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html), [Keep A Changelog](http://keepachangelog.com/) and my git plugin [git-semver](https://github.com/markchalloner/git-semver))

  `VERSION=0.1.0 && git tag ${VERSION} && git push origin ${VERSION}`
- add your package under require
- you can also use "dev-master" in your require if you don't want to add version tags and want to get the latest changes to package when running `composer update`. This requires setting:

  `minimum-stability: dev`

Final composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "multistepform",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/Test/Upload.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": "2.6.*",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*",
        "Test/Upload": "0.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}
```